# Can someone explain these confusing CPU temperature readings?

Tags: cpu, temperature, heatsink

So I'm running an i5 in an ASUS P8P67 M-Pro board and for whatever reason I'm getting some confusing tempature readings.

HW Monitor is reading my CPUTIN at 92C but my core temps are only at 38C.
I've re-done the heat sink twice, following the instructions for the Arctic Silver 5.

Can someone give me some advice on if this is actually running to hot or not?

Comment: Sure that's not 92F?

Answer (score 1):

I would not worry about it. A quick google search shows it's a common occurence. These sensors are added by the motherboard maker (rather than the CPU) and as such, may be not be well supported by various monitoring utilities or may not be high enough quality to report reliably at given temps. You could also check for a BIOS update on your MB.

The CPU core temps, on the other hand, are quite reliable (assuming non-defective CPU).

Check with your fingers on the board or heatsync near the CPU, and if it's warm but not enough to hurt, you're good to go and should ignore this temperature sensor entirely.

Answer (score 0):

All of the -TIN sensors on the P8P67 are unreliable. The CPU sensors are known-good, so stick with those temperatures.
If you'd like to be absolutely certain, you can pick up a cheap non-contact IR thermometer from a hobby shop.